I want replace the Marks column values when old values not suggestable?
select Name,Marks,
                 case
                 when Marks='65' then Roll_num='113'
                 when Marks='68' then Roll_num='114'
                 when Marks='71' then Roll_num='115'
                 else Roll_num 
                 end
from student;

I Want replace Marks column with new values. in this code i am not getting marks column replace values.

maybe so
SELECT
Name,
Marks,
CASE
when Marks='65' then '113'
when Marks='68' then '114'
when Marks='71' then '115'
ELSE Roll_num
END FROM    student;

SELECT Name, Marks, 
  CASE Marks 
   WHEN '65' THEN '113' 
   WHEN '68' THEN '114' 
   WHEN '71' THEN '115' 
   ELSE Roll_num 
  END AS Roll_num 
FROM student;

